# Placeholder Color Change in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I change the Placeholder Color in Bootstrap?

The following code, which I tried, doesn't work.

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: red;
}

input:-moz-placeholder {
        color: red;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to overwrite it with `!important`, something like `color: red !important;`

Comment: Try inspecting the CSS in your browser. You'll see what CSS has highest priority, then you can add more selectors to your code to have your CSS get higher priority. Or use `!important`.

Answer (score 43):

```
.form-control::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
            color: red;
            opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
            color: red;
}

.form-control::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
            color: red;
 }
```

The following is the reference link.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_placeholder.asp

Comment: just little update more

**color: red !important;**

Answer (score 16):

For Bootstrap 4, if you're using SCSS, just [override variable](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults) `$input-placeholder-color` before you import bootstrap.

```
// variable overrides
$input-placeholder-color: red;

// Bootstrap and its default variables
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Comment: Not working for me - placeholders are gray as they were.

Comment: Works with Bootstrap 5 as well.

Comment: Works as of today (BS 5.3.2). Documentation is here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/form-control/#sass-variables

Answer (score 9):

In Bootstrap 4 you change it like this:

```
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: but use !important as well

Comment: Probably best to work with bootstraps styling system, rather than overriding it with unknown interactions, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/60809492/1880657.

Comment: Works in BS 4.5

Answer (score 2):

Try the `!important` keyword

```
.input::placeholder {
     color: red !important;
     opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> It's work for me in bootstrap 5.3

```
input::placeholder {
    color: white !important;
}
input[type="text"]{
    padding-inline: 45px;
}
```